# Having trouble with MySQL exception

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I'm trying to make a WPF application. I have a datagrid inside my window. I have made another window that adds new data to my datagrid. While it works like I want, I keep getting an exception. My MySQL code:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestApp
{

    public class MySQLConnection
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string user;
        private string password;
        private int port;
        private string sslM;
        private MySqlDataAdapter adp;
        private MySqlCommandBuilder builder;
        //Constructor
        public MySQLConnection()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "pia";
            user = "root";
            password = "Timjar00";
            port = 3306;
            sslM = "None";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = string.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}; SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        //open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void updateDatatable(DataTable tb,DataGrid dg)
        {
            try
            {
                builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adp);
                adp.Update(tb);
                dg.ItemsSource = tb.DefaultView;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public DataTable FillDataTable(string query, DataTable tb)
        {
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                    adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    adp.Fill(tb);
                    adp.Dispose();
                    this.CloseConnection();
                }
                catch(MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
            return tb;
        }



        //Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }



        public void CreateTableIfNotExists(string query)
        {
            //string query = "CREATE TABLE testtable (name varchar(20));";

            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void Query(string query)
        {
            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void InsertmultipleOne(string query, int amount)
        {
            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {

                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++)
                {
                    string quer = string.Format(query, i);
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(quer, connection);
                    //Execute command
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        public void InsertmultipleTwo(string query, int amount1, int amount2)
        {
            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                for (int i = 1; i <= amount1; i++)
                {
                    string quer = string.Format(query, amount2,i);
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(quer, connection);
                    //Execute command
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
        public void InsertMultipleThree(string query,string val1, string val2, string val3, string val4, string val5, string val6, string val7, string val8, string val9, bool? val10, bool? val11, bool? val12)
        {
            if(this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.Prepare();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DQvalue", val1.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DQIndexOf", val2.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIvalue", val3.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIIndexOf", val4.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AQvalue", val5.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AQIndexOf", val6.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AIvalueLoHi", val7.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AIIndexOf", val8.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", val9.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkBit", val10);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GND1", val11);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GND2", val12);
                //Execute command
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void ReadQueryToComboBox(string query, ComboBox cb,string columnName)
        {
            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    cb.Items.Add(rdr[columnName]);
                }
                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                rdr.Close();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }


        //Select statement
        public List<string>[] Select()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
            list[0] = new List<string>();
            list[1] = new List<string>();
            list[2] = new List<string>();

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
                    list[1].Add(dataReader["name"] + "");
                    list[2].Add(dataReader["age"] + "");
                }

                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return list;
            }
        }

        //Count statement
        public int CountTable(string tablaname)
        {
            string query = string.Format("SELECT Count(*) FROM {0}", tablaname);
            int Count = -1;

            //Open Connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Mysql Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //ExecuteScalar will return one value
                Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                return Count;
            }
            else
            {
                return Count;
            }
        }

        //Backup
        public void Backup()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
                int year = Time.Year;
                int month = Time.Month;
                int day = Time.Day;
                int hour = Time.Hour;
                int minute = Time.Minute;
                int second = Time.Second;
                int millisecond = Time.Millisecond;

                //Save file to C:\ with the current date as a filename
                string path;
                path = "C:\\MySqlBackup" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day +
            "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + "-" + millisecond + ".sql";
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "mysqldump";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}",
                    user, password, server, database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process process = Process.Start(psi);

                string output;
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                file.WriteLine(output);
                process.WaitForExit();
                file.Close();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to backup!");
            }
        }

        //Restore
        public void Restore()
        {
            try
            {
                //Read file from C:\
                string path;
                path = "C:\\MySqlBackup.sql";
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
                string input = file.ReadToEnd();
                file.Close();

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "mysql";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}",
                    user, password, server, database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;


                Process process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
                process.StandardInput.Close();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to Restore!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I bound my `FillDataTable()` method to my initialization code. The DataGrid gets properly populated, but when I open a new window that adds a new row to my database, I call my `fillDataTable()` function again.

I can see that the function `updateDatatable()` immediately jumps into my exception and i keep getting the following exception: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." for every record in my database, so if I have 3 rows, 3 messageboxes will be showed. I handle all my MySQL code inside this class and use the functions inside this class in the rest of my code.

Here's a stacktrace inside the `updateDataTable()` function:

```
>   TestApp.exe!TestApp.MySQLConnection.updateDatatable(System.Data.DataTable tb, System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dg) Line 79  C#
    TestApp.exe!TestApp.MainWindow.Row_Changed(object sender, System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e) Line 178 + 0x2e bytes   C#
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.OnRowChanged(System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e) + 0x36 bytes   
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.OnRowChanged(System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs args, System.Data.DataRow eRow, System.Data.DataRowAction eAction) + 0x4c bytes   
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanged(System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs args, System.Data.DataRow eRow, System.Data.DataRowAction eAction) + 0xa8 bytes    
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(System.Data.DataRow row, int proposedRecord, System.Data.DataRowAction action, bool isInMerge, bool suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, int position, bool fireEvent, out System.Exception deferredException) + 0x21e bytes 
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(System.Data.DataRow row, long proposedID, int pos, bool fireEvent) + 0xf5 bytes 
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.LoadDataRow(object[] values, bool fAcceptChanges) + 0x178 bytes   
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow() + 0x67 bytes   
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping mapping) + 0xc5 bytes 
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(System.Data.DataSet dataset, System.Data.DataTable datatable, string srcTable, System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer dataReader, int startRecord, int maxRecords, System.Data.DataColumn parentChapterColumn, object parentChapterValue) + 0xc6 bytes  
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[] dataTables, System.Data.IDataReader dataReader, int startRecord, int maxRecords) + 0x138 bytes  
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet dataset, System.Data.DataTable[] datatables, int startRecord, int maxRecords, string srcTable, System.Data.IDbCommand command, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) + 0xab bytes 
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[] dataTables, int startRecord, int maxRecords, System.Data.IDbCommand command, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) + 0xa1 bytes   
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable dataTable) + 0x6d bytes 
    TestApp.exe!TestApp.MySQLConnection.FillDataTable(string query, System.Data.DataTable tb) Line 93 + 0x10 bytes  C#
    TestApp.exe!TestApp.MainWindow.FillDatagrid() Line 193 + 0x2e bytes C#
    TestApp.exe!TestApp.MainWindow.Add_newRegel(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 769 + 0x8 bytes   C#
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x74 bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0xae bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x73 bytes  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) + 0x18 bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick() + 0x4b bytes  
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() + 0x55 bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) + 0xa6 bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) + 0x6c bytes 
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) + 0x30 bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x2e bytes  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x3f bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0xae bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, System.Windows.RoutedEvent newEvent) + 0x109 bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) + 0xc6 bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) + 0x30 bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x2e bytes  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x3f bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0xae bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x73 bytes  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x46 bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) + 0x1a bytes    
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x203 bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) + 0x45 bytes 
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport) + 0x62 bytes  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel) + 0x2d6 bytes 
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x428 bytes 
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x6b bytes   
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x9b bytes    
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) + 0x6b bytes    
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x52 bytes 
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x34 bytes    
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x131 bytes 
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) + 0xee bytes 
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0xb1 bytes  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x4a bytes  
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) + 0x5a bytes  
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x74 bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x2b bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1c bytes 
    TestApp.exe!TestApp.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes
```

I also found where my problem lies. In my main code I do the following:

```
private void Add_newRegel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReceptenPopup recept = new ReceptenPopup();
    if (recept.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        dt.Clear();
        receptenDg.ItemsSource = null;
        sqlstring = "Select * FROM Recepten";
        DataTable mydt = db.FillDataTable(sqlstring, dt);
        receptenDg.ItemsSource = mydt.DefaultView;
        mydt.RowDeleted += Row_Deleted;
        mydt.RowChanged += Row_Changed;
    }
}
```

To explain: when I open a new window, fill in the information, and click OK to add a new row to my database, the code in the else statement gets called. The part of the code where everything goes wrong is the `DataTable mydt = db.FillDataTable(sqlstring, dt);` part. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you pull out the stacktrace?

Comment: "While a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for the Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the original DataReader is closed." source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: That is very strange, In every MysqlDataReader I read data and directly close it. It should not happen. I close my connections everytime as well

Comment: You're not using `using` around any object in the code, not the connection or the command or the dataadapter. There is a substantial chance that this is the cause that your connection is not really closed as you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection, command, datareader and DataAdapter are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close them because they will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block.

It also guarantees that things are disposed even if an exception is thrown, which the posted code.doesn't do. Any alternative approach to achieving this ends up more complex than a `using` block, which makes it a no-brainer.

After shifting away from holding these things as class-level fields you will find that these problems will go away.

P.S. I would recommend against naming a class which is only distinguished from another by *case*.

It's also worth reading [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: P.S. Unrelated to the exception, but StreamReader and StreamWriter are also IDisposable, so should also be in `using` blocks, and again, don't need the close if you do that.

Comment: While I did manage to fix my exception problem with the using statements, I now have other issues. For now I'll accept this answer.